# Animating UIImageView flip from middle

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, flip

I'm trying for a while to build an ebook, flipping page (from left to right) and zooming.
So far I've tested a few projects but none of them was good enough to do both.
I've decided to build one of my own, so I started with basic flip animation like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;
    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5.0f;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    tapGesture.delegate = self;
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
}

#pragma mark - UIScrollView Delegate

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return self.imageView;
}

#pragma mark - UIGestureRecognizer Delegate

- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGestur
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    if (tapGestur.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

        [UIView transitionWithView:self.imageView duration:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight|UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
            if (!flipped) {
                self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2-IPAD-P.jpg"];
                flipped = YES;
            }
            else {
                self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1-IPAD-P.jpg"];
            }
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            //
        }];
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do now is transition flipping page (left to right) from the middle of the image.
Any idea how can I do this using UIVIew? Or maybe better options?

Comment: Hi Idan, i am trapped in same scenario.. Can you please guide?

Answer (score 0):

You should also give a look to `CATansition`. Have a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973983/how-does-the-catransition-work).

Also, have you looked at UIViewAnimationOptions's `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp` and `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown` for page animations ?