# How to use CATransition type and subType

Tags: ios, types, catransition, subtype

Can any one please share the importance of CATransition type and subType properties.I have been playing with these two properties but not able to find out the difference when running the app.May be, i am not using the way it is supposed to be used.Could anyone tell clearly when to use subType? and is there any connection between type and subtype.When to use what and how to figure out what are to be used in which kind of transition effects to be made.

I am not having any kind of idea.i am just empty with this usage.Best explanations with example would be much appreciated and up voted.

Answer (score 0):

The CATransition class implements transition animations for a layer. You can specify the transition effect from a set of predefined transitions or by providing a custom CIFilter instance. 
I hop this link full fill your requirement [how does the CATransition work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973983/how-does-the-catransition-work)

Comment: Thanks.will be looking to figure out from shared link.